# Why does Mal change his mind?

Tags: firefly, serenity

In the episode [Safe](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Safe), Mal comes back to rescue Simon.

> **SIMON** Captain... why did you come back for us?
>
> **MAL** You're on my crew.
>
> **SIMON** Yeah, but you don't even like me. (beat) Why'd you come back?
>
> **MAL** You're on my crew. Why we still talking about this? (walks off,
>   over his shoulder) Chow's in ten. No need to dress.

Again in the episode [Ariel](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Ariel_(episode)), Mal threatens to allow Jayne to get sucked into space for betraying the Tams to the Alliance.

But then, at the beginning of the movie [Serenity](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Serenity_(film)), Mal tells Simon, "I look out for me and mine. That don't include you unless I conjure it does."

I was wondering if there was any indication in the books or extra media that would indicate why Mal had this change of heart?

Comment: A guy can't change his mind?

Comment: See the answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50760/why-does-mal-abandon-the-tams-in-safe?rq=1)

Comment: I reckon Mal never intended to leave Simon and River. The reasoning I assume he’s having is: “I got an entire planet to scour to find my doctor and I got a person who’s going to die in a couple hours unless I get qualified medical attention right now. If I don’t find my doctor in a couple of hours, Book dies. The likelihood of me taking this little time to find Tams is really low. The likelihood of Tams lasting a bit longer than Book is quite some higher. So I attend to Book first, Tams later."

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It was pretty heavily implied (by Kaylee, IIRC - I don't have the book or the film to reference right now) that Mal has been more angry and moody since Inara left the ship. With both Inara and Book gone, Mal's lost his stabilizing influences. He's becoming erratic, ruthless, and mean-spirited. It's the same reason he was willing to drive away and leave the man in the town to the Reavers rather than bringing him along.

Comment: While your point is actually even more legit than mine, I disagree about the Reaver part. The man simply couldn't have been saved - reavers were too many, and Jayne didn't have grenades - so what Mal did was mercy killing.

Comment: But as Zoe says when she confronts him about it, "Back in the war, we would've never left a man behind." His reply "Maybe that's why we lost."  The point being that even Zoe is noticing a change in Mal's behavior, enough to comment on it.

Comment: Back in war Mal didn't have anything but the Browncoats to worry about. He was reckless, committed. Now he has a crew to care for, as he points out in the remainder of the conversation you just quoted.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue whether his choice was justified or not - just pointing out that Zoe, who knows him best, seems to think he's changing, and becoming more ruthless.

Comment: I agree. But it appears to me that she only compares captain-Mal to sergeant-Mal. She doesn't mention Inara or Shepherd. Mal is aware of the change, in the beginning of the film he says "War's long done. We're all just folk now."

Comment: I think this is basically right, but I want to add something: the quote was "I look out for me and mine. That don't include you unless I conjure it does.". This change in attitude has caused him to no longer 'conjure' that SImon is one of his own.

Comment: @DCShannon  -  what do you mean?

Comment: @Gallifreyan: [Malcolm Reynolds was a captain in the war, and also the highest ranking Browncoat to participate in and survive the Battle of Serenity Valley](https://firefly.fandom.com/wiki/Malcolm_Reynolds). Even in the war, Mal had people under his command. He wasn't just looking out for himself then either.

Answer (score 15):

I don't see how he changes his mind.

He comes back for Simon because:

1. Simon is very **useful**
2. Simon is **reliable**, since he also needs the cap'n in order to keep River and himself safe from the Alliance.

He then threatens Jayne because latter is a betrayer scum. But then again, Mal probably knew this moment would come - Jayne changed his allegiance in *Out of Gas*, and the only reason why he didn't betray Mal in *Serenity* (ep. 1) is "*money wasn't good enough*". Yet Jayne saw what happens when one bargains with the Alliance, and Mal knows that. So he pokes Jayne just a bit, so that the **lesson is well-received**. Indeed, Jayne is sorry, and Mal is assured that Jayne is "one of his crew" once again.

And lastly, when Mal says

> that don't include you unless I conjure it does

He wants to be clear that although a crew member may be useful, Simon in particular comes with difficulties as well, as he continues to explain,

> You stuck a thorn in the Alliance's paw. That tickles me a bit. But it also means I have to step twice as fast to avoid them, and that means turning down plenty of jobs. Even honest ones.

Still, the Captain seems cold, but IMHO he wouldn't abandon anyone just like that (what happens later in *Serenity* is another thing entirely). Kaylee actually says the exact same thing after she is treated, in episode 1.

Comment: I would argue that he comes back for Simon because "You're on my crew." He had accepted them as family, or at least that's how I took it.

Comment: @BrendanHughes  -  I regarded Mal's *crew* equivalent to *family* in this case.

Answer (score 11):

An out-of-universe answer, which I realize isn’t necessarily the goal here, but I feel that getting meta is the only way to make that scene from *Serenity* make sense.

I always treated the plot of *Serenity* as including a condensed version of the *Firefly* continuity, for the sake of audiences unfamiliar with the show. Thus, we see Mal and Simon’s frosty early relationship, because it’s crucial to understanding Mal and Simon’s characters.

I would therefore say that the quote you have from *Serenity* took place prior to “Safe” and “Ariel.”

This doesn’t *quite* make sense (for instance, the statement is made in part in reference to River being taken on a job for the first time, but *Firefly* certainly gave no indication that such a thing had ever happened even off-screen), which is why I say *Serenity* included a condensed version of the *Firefly* continuity. Thus, the events of both *Firefly* and *Serenity* took place, but not in exactly the way they’re presented in *Serenity*, and not strictly ordered among the episodes of *Firefly* (though clearly nothing of *Firefly* takes place after the main events of *Serenity*).

Comment: +1 Great point. The film worked so well because they were willing to make it standalone rather than just a final episode. That meant playing with the characters a bit to provide drama for people who didn't know them.

Comment: The opening scene where Simon rescues River is not that consistent with the series either, unless you squint quite hard, but again, for the film it is perfect.

Comment: Except the reason Mal includes River in the mission is because "she's a reader". This is something they don't realize until at least midway through the TV series and the characters don't voice their suspicions to each other until the final episode. But by the beginning of Serenity, they've all accepted that fact so the movie must occur in its entirety after the events of the TV series.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that Mal never intended to leave Simon behind, but that he was a) being moody, and b) teaching Simon a little bit about himself and what to expect.

Comment: Yeah, you’re probably right about (a). But as far “teaching Simon about himself,” surely Simon already was familiar with Mal’s personality by that point?

Comment: Well, for whatever reason, Mal felt compelled (maybe he was just cranky) to make it clear to Simone that if he ever were to do something to make Mal decide he wasn't part of the crew, he'd be on his own. An affirmation of the need for loyalty, of sorts.